# View in views header still displaying when no result

Tags: blocks, views

I tried this question:
[Empty view is rendered even though there is no result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87963/empty-view-is-rendered-even-though-there-is-no-result)

And it didn't work

I have a view of Judge nodes that displays using a contextual filter. Inside that view I have embedded a view block into the header that displays a Featured Judge, passing it the contextual filters and left 'Display even if no results' unchecked. In the Featured Judge view I have set it to not display empty fields. Also I have added a filter to a field as suggested in the question above.

Still I get the following output in the views header:

```
<div class="view view-featured-judge view-id-featured_judge view-display-id-block view-dom-id-0cfff43385fef2dba170ae09d3f818cf"></div>
```

I have dpm'd the views array in preprocess view, and results is empty. I have set it to NULL and it still displays. At present the only solution appears to be to check if the results array is empty and if so add a class to display: none; which is frankly ludicrous.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you copy paste the HTML content of the View Listing of Judge Nodes. I doubt that empty rows are still getting printed and that could be the cause. HTML will help to understand the problem

Comment: There are no empty rows printed in the header (where the view is) the html for it is quoted above in the question. It is inside the view-header div for the parent view.

Comment: do you use a relationship in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have added the filter only for the Featured Judge View.

Try adding a filter in the View that lists the Judge Nodes. This will completely note render the whole view at all.

Comment: No, even with that filter added to the parent view, it displays the child view in the header. This shouldn't make a difference anyway, they are totally different views