# use "php code" in page manager access rules to evaluate if current og_group has content of a specific type

Tags: organic-groups, chaos-tool-suite

I'm grateful for the amazing organic groups module (and so many other drupal modules), which I am using for a civil society and social economy network platform.

I have a question, which I think would be interesting for others too. I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Usecase: I have a page (in page manager) which outputs a tab in og_group nodes, showing a view panel pane of og_group content (together with other panes). Specifically, og_group are organizations, and og_group contents are events. So I'm showing events of each organization in a separete tab.

I wish this tab "events" to be visibile only if there is at least one node of type "event" listed as group content of the og_group page being viewed.

In order to do this, I am trying to use page manager "access rules", which, to quote specific documentation:

> are used to test if the page is accessible and any menu items
>   associated with it are visible.

The "only" og related rules available are:

> "Node is an OG group" 
>   "Node is an OG group content" 
>   "user membership in group" 
>   "user permissions in group"

So, I think my logic is possible with the generic "php code" rule. But I'm no coder, yet.

Anybody could give me a hint about what code should I write to check if te viewed node (which is an OG group) has at least one event associated with it as group content?

Thanks!!!

Config: D7 7.41, php 5.2.4, panopoly 7.x-1.28, og 7.x-2.7, ctools 7.x-1.8, panels 7.x-3.5

Update: as @Stefanos suggested in his answer, I am searching for a kind of "no results" behavior of views module, in page manager.

@Stefanos, here is the context available in the page:
[image]

Comment: Hey Miro, could you post a list of the $contexts available in the php code rule? You need to have the devel module installed and then you could get them on your screen by placing this into the php textarea: dpm($contexts);

Comment: yes, thanks, I added a print screen in the question!

Comment: I didn't expand all objects in the picture, but inside data there is nid, for instance. I'm trying to evaluate something like this `empty(views_get_view_result('rbv_view_group_content','panel_pane_3','$node->nid'));`, with no success yet! It is the related view with contextual filter that I am trying to get.

Comment: Hey Miro, updated my answer below, you can try the code at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer: To do this with the code you provided, you should use something like the following:

```
$node = $contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data;
$args = array($node->nid‌​);
return empty(views_get_view_result('rbv_view_group_content','panel_pane_3',$args));
```

Alternative answer: I have an alternative suggestion, and unless you absolutely want to use the Page Manager, it should allow you to solve your problem without any coding.

So, if you read so far... :-), I would suggest using Views and setting up a path that will 'link' your view to your group node's URL. You are probably already using a view to list your Events. You can set up a page for that view that has a path like the following:

```
node/%nid/events
```

You should further configure your page to be rendered as a "Menu Tab", titled "Events".

This Views Page will now be linked to your Group page, and you will be able to handle its behaviour in the case of no results (Events) for that og_group node; for your case to simply hide it.

To get this all working, you would also need to set up your contextual filters to use the og_group nid.

This is a bit theoretical, but I am not entirely sure of your setup.
I hope it helps you though!

Comment: Hi Stefano, thank you very much for your answer. Yes, if I would go for a views generated page, I believe your suggestion to configure the no results behavior is viable. Thanks! I wish to use page manager because it's a panopoly based website, so I use panels, and I wish to add more panel panes to the "events" page.. I will update my question. Any other good hint? :-)

Comment: Hi, and thanks again! I used the code you suggested, and the tab menu behave correctly, only being displayed in groups which has some events. But, when I hit the tab button, I have a 500 internal server error...

Comment: Hey @Miro, glad to know you are a step further. Since I don't know all the details of your panel, could you try disabling your panel's panes in order to find out which one is causing the problem? Then we can try to find out what is causing the 500 error. If you deactivate the selection php code, do you still get the error?

Comment: Ok, I did disabled all panel panes in the page. 500 still there. If I deactivate the php access rule, everything is visible, no errors, but on all pages. Same if I substitute php code with `return true;`.

Comment: My code is a bit different than what you suggested. I didn't use the array: `return !empty(views_get_view_result('rbv_view_group_content','panel_pane_3', $contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data->nid));`. If I put the contextual filter inside an array, `return !empty(views_get_view_result('rbv_view_group_content','panel_pane_3', array($contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data->nid)));` , I got the 500 in the page, plus a Warning in the main page saying: "array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 175 of /includes/entity.inc)."

Comment: Sorry about that, I have to check again the argument parameter, thought views_get_view_result expected an array. Why don't you try to add a sanity check for the $contexts variable, e.g. if( isset($contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']) ) { then do BLOCK } else return true;

Comment: Thanks @Stefanos I did it, with no success. If I write this code `drupal_set_message($contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data->nid);
return true;` I can see the right nid printed on each page, so the context part works fine. The problem is, I believe, in the view part. I'll check that out.

Comment: Nope, the view part is working fine too. If I write `drupal_set_message(!empty(views_get_view_result('rbv_view_group_content','panel_pane_3',$contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data->nid)));` it corectly shows `1` only in the nodes with some events. But if I want to use the code to return true/false (I assume 1 is true), it doesn't work. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Even if I add `(bool)` before the condition, to be shure it returns a boolean, it doesn't work. So, do you think it is possible to assume the problem is in page manager access rules component?

Comment: It's not easy to find out what triggers the error, not from the outside world. You could - for correctness - try to make your access rules more specific, by adding more conditions. For example, checking the Node: Bundle AND the php code. But, this is a wild guess, I have too little insight at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36974/discussion-between-miro-marchi-and-stefanos-petrakis).

Comment: Finally I got it working. The problem was in my views, which were counting one result even for nodes where I would expect no results. I managed to get them working properly, adding a filter to the views checking field "is not empty". Apparently when the view has contextual filter always return one result by default. I got the idea from the answer @Mohammed Shameem gave to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87963/empty-view-is-rendered-even-though-there-is-no-result). Thanks both of you!

Comment: Great to hear @miro, take care!